# Angular2 routing navigate to same page after http service request

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

In my Angular2 project, I am displaying a list of users and I have an add button, when I add a new user without refreshing the page I wanted to display the newly added user to my currently displaying user list.I have come up with the following solution but here in my subscriber.component.ts file I am calling this.getSubscribers(); function twice, for the first time it is giving null pointer exception. what might be the solution? Is there any other approach other than what I am currently using for displaying without refreshing ?
Here is my code..

subscriber.component.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let subscriber of mf.data">
          <td>{{subscriber.name}}</td>
          <td>{{subscriber.email}}</td>
          <td>{{subscriber.mdn}}</td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <md-icon (click)="goToSubscriberDetails(subscriber)" mdTooltip="View Details">
              remove_red_eye
            </md-icon>
            <md-icon mdTooltip="Edit" (click)="openEditDialog(subscriber)">edit</md-icon>
            <md-icon mdTooltip="Recharge" (click)="rechargeDialog(subscriber)">attach_money</md-icon>
          </td>
        </tr>
```

subscriber.component.ts

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.currentPage = 1;
    this.pageStart = 0;
    this.subscriberService
      .getSubscribers(0, 10, this.currentPage).subscribe(data => {
      this.subscribers = data.data;
      this.totalSubscriberLength = data.total;
    });
    this.sharedService.notifySubscriberObservable$.subscribe((res) => {
      this.getSubscribers();  // null pointer exception
      this.getSubscribers();
      console.log("in Subscriber template refresh")
    });
  }
```

adddialog.component.ts

```
 this.subscriberService.addSubscriber(data).subscribe(data => {
      let responseJson=data.json();
      if (responseJson.success)
      {
        this.toasterService.pop('success', 'SUCCESS', SUBSCRIBER_ADD_SUCCESS_MESSAGE);
        this.sharedService.notifyOtherSubscriber();
      }

      else
        this.toasterService.pop('error', 'FAILED',SUBSCRIBER_ADD_FAILURE_MESSAGE);
    }
```

global.ts

```
private notify = new Subject<any>();
  notifyObservable$ = this.notify.asObservable();
  constructor(){}
  public notifyOther()
  {
    this.notify.next();
  }
  private notifySubscriber = new Subject<any>();
  notifySubscriberObservable$ = this.notifySubscriber.asObservable();
  public notifyOtherSubscriber() {
    this.notifySubscriber.next();
  }
```

Comment: It can be done by simply pushing element in the list of Array

Comment: If you want help with what is happening to `this.getSubscribers()`, then you should probably include the `this.getSubscribers()` code in your question :)

Comment: getSubscribers(): void {
    this.subscriberService
      .getSubscribers(0, 10, this.currentPage).subscribe(data => this.subscribers = data.data);
  }

Comment: It there any other alternative other than Observables ?